# Sequelize instantiation parameters

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm very new to sequelize and I'm currently studying their V6 docs and I saw this code line

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');
```

What does this part `sqlite::memory:` mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That means sequelize will use SQLite dialect, and SQLite uses a new database is created purely in memory. See [In-Memory Databases](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)